# what is best no sql db for user profile management

Tags: mongodb, performance, cassandra, hbase, nosql

I need to manage user profiles. The number of user profiles could be very big (500 millions profiles)
The system requirements is update those profiles (maybe once a day, a week, or by request), and always read them at runtime.

Which no sql database could be most suitable to this feature? mongodb, cassandra or hbase ?

I'm using now the mongodb (with sharding), one of the problems I see in it that it has a global lock, and each time I'm doing lot's of writes my reads performance is going down. 
And since the runtime component always should read some profile the performance is critical.

Moreover, maybe should I use some cache technology in addition?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you aware of some Cassandra configuration specifics that I should take in account for the described task?

Comment: I haven't used it in production myself. But I heard that you should let your disk usage go above 50% (it needs space for compactions and stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Performance tuning is a critical part when it comes to no-sql database.

2) I have been using Cassandra for over an year and as writes are sequential they are faster like anything.I have seen faster performance with [sstableloader](http://www.shareitexploreit.blogspot.in/2012/02/cassandra-bulk-loader.html) and [BulkOutPutFrormat](http://www.shareitexploreit.blogspot.in/2012/03/bulkloadto-cassandra-with-hadoop.html)

3) But read performance is really a concern and can be tuned with various parameters and also depends on the way you model the data(database schema).

4) But If you design it considering how Cassandra works reads are also faster. But if you are using any of the Bulkloading strategy mentioned above you may experience relatively more read latency during data load

5) As User data is kind of critical one for availability purpose you should consider larger replication factor.

Comment: Which configuration/runtime specifics could you advice me to take a look?

Comment: @Julias read performance with Cassandra is affected more by your data model than any configuration options.  I suggest reading some articles on data modeling; feel free to ask for specific questions about your data model here or on the user mailing list afterwards.

Comment: @Julias Tyler Hobbs is right Its mainly depends on the way you design your data model. For configuration you can go through the cassandra configuration file i.e cassandra.yaml which comes with sufficient description of each parameter.